# Create a price table without using table in html design

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a pricing table without using table tag.

Please find the below code for the sample,

Sample Link: https://jsfiddle.net/rk34v1fa/

```
<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Basic</li>
    <li class="grey"><ul class="price">
        <li class="grey">$ 9.99 / year</li>
                <li class="grey">$ 9.99 / year</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li>10GB Storage</li>
    <li>10 Emails</li>
    <li>10 Domains</li>
    <li>1GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header" style="background-color:#4CAF50">Pro</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 24.99 / year</li>
    <li>25GB Storage</li>
    <li>25 Emails</li>
    <li>25 Domains</li>
    <li>2GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Premium</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 49.99 / year</li>
    <li>50GB Storage</li>
    <li>50 Emails</li>
    <li>50 Domains</li>
    <li>5GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is the row line(cell height is not even) is not proper. for example if the basic 1st cell has more value the cell height is increased so the it's not even height for another cell also

Comment: set a height and use ellipsis https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Comment: There is a lot of example on the internet! For example look at this link: http://blog.dynamicdrive.com/free-comparison-and-pricing-table-templates/

Comment: @SaeedHassanvand thanks nice to see.. but those all are using table i am checking without table

Answer (score 1):

I usually tend to use CSS Grid. It gives you more abilities of doing changes and it is more clean.
If you would like to try it; include this css lines in your file:

```
#priceTable{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: 200px;
}
```

this is going to style the table you have in the left bottom of your page.
so you can also change the wrapping div before the last wrapping div into the following:

```
<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price" id="priceTable">
    <li class="header" style="background-color:#4CAF50">Pro</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 24.99 / year</li>
    <li>25GB Storage</li>
    <li>25 Emails</li>
    <li>25 Domains</li>
    <li>2GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```